# Modified random one dimensional walk problem

Tags: probability

If I take one step right from my initial position, I will fall off a cliff. My goal is to get to safety, which is exactly $x$ steps to my left. I decide which direction I will make my next step by flipping a coin. What is the probability that I will fall off the cliff before making it to safety?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_i$ be the probability that you will survive given that you are currently $i$ steps to the left of the cliff. Then $p_0 = 0$ and $p_{x+1} = 1$. Furthermore, since you move randomly, $p_i = \frac{1}{2}(p_{i-1}+p_{i+1})$ if $0 < i \le x$. Thus the sequence $p_i$ is an arithmetic sequence with common difference $\frac{1}{x+1}$, and it follows that our desired probability $p_1$ is $\frac{1}{x+1}$.

Comment: In the question, safety is $x+1$ steps away from the cliff, not $x$ steps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the common difference is $1/(x+1)$. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Because each $p_i$ is the average of the previous and the next $p_i$, the sequence $\{p_i\}$ is an arithmetic sequence. In $x+1$ terms, this sequence goes from $p_0 = 0$ to $p_{x+1} = 1$, hence the difference between consecutive terms is $\frac{1}{x+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_k$ be the probability that you will reach safety starting from position $k$ (steps away from cliff), for each $k \in \{0\dots x+1\}$.

Then for every $k \in \{1 \dots x\}$ we have $p_k = \frac12 p_{k-1} + \frac12 p_{k+1}$ and hence $p_k-p_{k-1} = p_{k+1}-p_k$.

Also $p_0 = 0$ and $p_{x+1} = 1$.

Therefore you can work out all the other values since the consecutive differences are equal.